# How to train the passagio in a female voice?

Tags: voice-training

I'm an inexperienced singer. I love singing and have a decent "ear" for music, but my voice is very weak. This means that my range of full (chest) voice finishes very, very low. On the other hand, I can hit quite high notes (I was classified as soprano). The most problematic notes are notes "between" - I'm very quiet when I sing them, and it doesn't sound good at all.

My question is: How to improve this in-between range?

Comment: consider my answer to this question here: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/90301/singing-effect-of-vowels-on-tuning-and-tonality/90304#90304 (this exercise is also fine to train the lower registers.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the transition between the chest voice and the head voice to sound smooth is a matter of coordination, which can be improved by training. Two exercises that helped me quite a bit in that aspect are:

- start humming a tone, then slide up a fifth, then slide down a fifth. Start again a half-step higher, fifth up, fifth down (you can use [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zLbn2Vic33E) as a reference). Focus on the range where the lower tone is in your chest voice, and the higher is in your head voice.
- sing triads up and down on vowels (a, ee, o, u) (use [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rm9zIm0OZtQ) for guidance). Focus on the range where you have to switch between chest voice and head voice.

At the transition, experiment with different resonances. You can extend the range of your chest voice upward if you "push the sound into the nose" (it's hard to explain, but you'll know when you feel it). Try to switch between frontal resonance chest voice and head voice on the same note.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need more breath training.  If your vocal control and ear is good, but your projection is weak, its likely that you need to improve your diaphragm strength and work on pacing. Eg. knowing when to pause and inhale in preparation for the next passage.

Here's a good start.  http://www.vocalist.org.uk/breathing_exercises.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your voice might be kind of airy in your low/mid range?
One breathing exercise that you can try is: you inhale diafragmatically and then retain all the air in your body as if you were under water. And now try to speak letting the minimum amount of air go out as possible. With this you can achieve a more clear sound, and then replace speaking with singing.

To keep the air from being released all at once, you can think about stuff like being under water, blowing a candle without putting the light out... The key is to keep the air in your lungs and release it little by little.